# In place list modification on a list of objects

Tags: python

Stack folks,

I'm trying to complete a project where customers purchase a bike. Both the customers and the bikes available (inventory) are in lists. What I'm running into is updating the inventory list when a bike is purchased. The bikes and customers are objects.

My question is, once I find a bike that a customer can purchase, how can I modify the inventory list so any following customers don't evaluate this in their purchase (because a customer before them bought the bike)?

Here's what I have so far.

```
print '\nPurchasing'
print '-' * 20
for i in range(len(customer_list)):
    for b in range(len(inventory_list)):
        if inventory_list[b].shopCost <= customer_list[i].cust_funds:
            print "{0} ---- {1} --- {2}".format(customer_list[i].cust_name, inventory_list[b].modelName, inventory_list[b].shopCost)
```

Attempted code:

```
if inventory_list[b].shopCost <= customer_list[i].cust_funds and inventory_list[b].soldFlag is False:
    del inventory_list[b]
```

but I get an index out or range error when using this.

Any help is *greatly* appreciated

Comment: just set your soldFlag to true instead of deleting it ... in general you should avoid adding/removing from a list while iterating over it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it is because you are deleting something and then using the same index for accessing information of the item (this is dangerous). I what about just skipping the deleted items in a loop, or delete them and use a `continue` (see example below).

but maybe simplify your code and see if this works:

```
print '\nPurchasing'
print '-' * 20
for cust in customer_list:
    for item in inventory_list:
        if item.shopCost <= cust.cust_funds
            if item.soldFlag is False:
                inventory_list.remove(item)
                continue
        if item.shopCost <= cust.cust_funds:
            print "{0} ---- {1} --- {2}".format(cust.cust_name, item.modelName, item.shopCost)
```